# How do you prevent an Android View from drawing its Background

Tags: android, view

In Android I have a class which extends View. Under certain circumstances I want it to not draw itself. I realize I could setVisibility() to View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE, but I would rather avoid that if possible. There are other parts of code behave differently if this custom view is or is not visible, and I don't want to rewrite those if I don't have to.

Originally I thought it would be as easy as overriding onDraw(), similar to the following...

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   if(...){ //check some member variables
      return;
   } else {
      //draw code
   }
}
```

This worked for most of the view, but I found that the background would still show up regardless of the result of my conditional check. After reading the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) a bit I found this...

> "Drawing is handled by walking the tree and rendering each view that intersects the invalid region. Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will draw before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree. If you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw it for you before calling back to its onDraw() method."

The solution I came up with is a bit of a hack...

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   if(...){ //check some member variables
      //set background to transparent
      return;
   } else {
      //restore default background
      //draw code
   }
}
```

So I guess my question becomes this: Is there any way to override the default background drawing behavior for a view so that I don't have to change the Visibility or Background of the view?

Comment: making a view not render itself is quite similar to make it invisible. I don't see a reason why not the visibility system, since it exists already and all.

Comment: Suppose for instance it was the case that I wanted to draw it differently (instead of not drawing it at all). Is there a way to branch on a conditional and draw the background one of two distinct ways?

Comment: Can't you just *change* the background in that case?

Comment: I can change the background color within the onDraw() call, but the background has already been drawn at this point. It forces me to call invalidate() on the view and trigger the drawing code all over again. This is the 2nd solution I mentioned in my question, but it's far from ideal. I would much rather intercept the code BEFORE the background is drawn and branch on a conditional at that point.

Comment: You can change the background when the condition changes instead of in `onDraw()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The background is drawn during the `draw()` method, not the `onDraw()` method. You could override that, but it does a hell of a lot more than just draw the background, so that's not really an option.

As per the comments above, your best bet is to just change the background programmatically.

EDIT: So yes, you could override `draw()` and override the background before calling through to `super.draw()`.